# Twentyseventeen theme customize bug

Tags: theme-customizer, theme-twenty-seventeen

I have been trying to work out an issue with a clean install of wordpress using the customizer for the TwentySeventeen theme.

I use the latest version of the theme.
In the details it states that it should be working with Wordpress 5.8 (I'm using 5.8.2 but also tried 5.8.1 and 5.8.0)

Every time I want to go into the customizer to change some parts of the theme I am greeted with a blank page with no preview or options in the left sidebar.
The only thing I get is "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'" in the custimize.php line 5470 (which doesn't exist in the code)

To reiterate This is a completely clean install of wordpress with no plugins active nor installed.
The theme is installed from the theme manager in wordpress itself but also tried downloading it and putting it in the themes folder (which I know is basically the same).

When searching online I don't get any info that really helps me.
All the solutions that are in line with something resembling my issue are for custom themes and don't apply my situation.

Any idea what might be causing this issue and how to solve it?

Regards

Comment: you probably have wordpress debug active, some themes have been done a long time ago and new versions of wordpress turn on this debug messages, if you dont have wordpress debug active that seems to be some theme bug on the code, there is a function somewhere in the code that is making worpress code give you that error. try with twentytwentyone theme , or another theme to see if it does the same thing. this way you know for sure if is the theme that is causing this.

Comment: @tiagocalado thank you for your reply. I checked if that was the case but debug was turned off. I also tried different themes but those themes work normally. it is only the TwentySeventeen theme by wordpress team themselves.

Comment: yes, if that only happens in that theme, is the theme for sure. the only thing I can recommend you is to delete the theme and install it again

Comment: Well then It seems my only option is to build the theme from scratch myself then -_-
I already reinstalled the theme 5 times. Anyway thanks for the suggestions